# How to record audio from loud speaker?

Tags: android, voice-recording

Does anyone know what source should I use if I want to record sound from the loud speaker rather than microphone? 
this is what I have but of course this is recording from MIC.

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
```

I have ahad a look at the document and I can't find anything tthere even is not clear what exactly VOICE_DOWNLINK,VOICE_UPLINK and VOICE_COMMUNICATION means?

Here is the link to the document. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html

I would highly appreciate if someone could advice me on that?

Any comment is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Loud speaker, as name indicates is a speaker. to record what goes out of loud speaker you should use microphone. You cannot intercept audio stream that goes to the loudspeaker other way

Comment: Thanks @WebnetMobile.com. SO this means if I use microphone as the input I can record everything is coming out of the speaker as well as microphone?

Comment: yes and no - please note there are two type of speakers: `loud speaker` and `speaker`. The mic will most likely be able to "hear" loud speaker but not normal speaker

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com would it be possible if audio that's going to speaker is output of Text to speech engine in my own app and I want to inspect PCM data of that to apply some visualization (like a speaking robot app)?